# Spring Cloud Gateway inside k8s - routes are not being load balanced

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring-cloud-gateway 2021.0.0 inside a k8s cluster. I also have one k8s service with 2 pods. My issue is that the spring gateway is always routing the traffic to the same pod. If I remove that pod then the spring gateway starts using the other one. How can I configure the spring gateway to use all the pods associated with the k8s service? I know that the k8s service is working fine because if a enter the gateway container and do a curl to the service, the request goes sometime to one pod and sometime to the other, but like I said, using the spring gateway the requests go always to the same pod.

**My spring Gateway config**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: product
          uri: http://product-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/product/**
```

If I change the uri and put `lb` instead of `http` i get an 503

```
spring.cloud.gateway.requests tags: [tag(httpMethod=GET),tag(httpStatusCode=503),tag(outcome=SERVER_ERROR),tag(routeId=product),tag(routeUri=lb://product-service),tag(status=SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)]
```

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I found the issue here https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections
I just set the httpClient keepAlive property to false, and now it is working as expected

Comment: This [Spring Cloud Gateway issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/561) has a work around that configures the Netty DNS resolver cache.

Comment: Thanks @ChinHuang for the lead. I have follow the steps and disable the DNS cache on NEtty but still having the same issue and the spring cloud gateway is still sending all the request to one of the pods

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable client side load balancing by adding kubernetes and kubernetes-lb starter dependencies in your gateway application. Also need to user config of routes as lb://service-name rather using http endpoint. It will do load balacing in round-robin fashion.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-loadbalancer</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi rubalvjaiswal, I'm using neither Spring Cloud Netflix Eureka for service discovery nor Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon/Spring Cloud Load Balancer for load balancing in my project, just Spring Cloud Gateway because Kubernetes provides service discovery and load balancing natively

Comment: You need to add these dependecy if you are using lb://service-name to resolve 503 gateway error.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still stuck with the question. I managed to solve it by adding the following dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-loadbalancer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Besides that, the following property should be added to `application.properties`, which enables load balancing based on **Kubernetes Service name**.

```
spring.cloud.kubernetes.loadbalancer.mode=SERVICE
```

Also, routes' URI should be defined with the `lb` scheme instead of `http` or `https`.

For reference: [Spring Cloud Kubernetes documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#loadbalancer-for-kubernetes)